# Можно ли использовать 445 порт для обращения к API?

Tags: nginx, сеть, fastapi

Вопрос к специалистам по сетям. Опустим мою мотивацию и советы использовать другие порты.

Можно ли использовать данный порт для обращения к API в таком виде

```
curl my.domain:445/any/url
```

Пытаюсь настроить и не получаю положительного результата. Порт открыт, файрволлы проверены и порт открыт для всех.

принимающий сервер Ubuntu 22.04,
связка для тестов с API -> nginx, guvicorn, unicorn, fastApi (локально проверено, проблем нет)

Comment: так как на 445 порту обычно расположена виндовая служба доступа к различным ресурсам и так как в ней исторически было огромное количество уязвимостей, то многие провайдеры полностью блокируют данный порт, причем как можно ближе к абоненту

Comment: Можно, у меня такая команда успешно работает. Вы уверены, что у вас на порту 445 есть кто-то, кто принимает запросы на порту http? Вы уверены, что порт 445 никем не фильтруется по дороге?

Comment: @Mike есть ли возможность определить эту блокировку? `verbose`-mode для curl ничего не показывает...

Comment: @andreymal nginx там принимет, проверил с самого сервера по имени хоста, nginx отдает правильный овтет

Comment: технически можно, но зачем жрать кактус?

Comment: @AlexeyTen иногда правила игры определяет смежный и не тактичный отдел) с детскими хотелками и отличным понимаением к какой ситуации их действия могут привести

Comment: блокировку определить просто. Если на машине где поднят nginx локально можно подключиться к порту (используя внешний ip адрес) а например у вас из дома нельзя, то значит где то по дороге он блокируется и скорее всего где то очень близко к дому (потому как на магистральных каналах обычно ничего не блокируется)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кто будет искать ответ, то коротко: "Да, можно".

Проблема заключалась только в iptables правилах, которые автоматически прописываются при использовании `ufw`-утилиты. Отследил цепочки, посмотрел где происходит `DROP` при обращении по данному порту и изменил на поведение, которое я ожидаю.

Все работает.